# CSS: image not centering with display: block margin: 0 auto?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on creating a photo gallery with a thumbnail slider and the only issue I'm having is that of centering the image within the div.

I've tried using the normal:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

but that only messed up how the images loaded above the div i'm using.

Here is a JSFiddle of how it looks now: http://jsfiddle.net/bWk24/

Thank you to all, in advance!

Comment: for those of you who are confused by the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wks7m/

Comment: I have notised that not all of the element you are trying to center have widths, which is required for centering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image is positioned absolutely.

You need to add

```
img {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

So the `margin: 0 auto;` tries to position itself in the middle, absolutely from the sides of its relative parent.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nHLpz/

Answer (score 4):

Take out the position `absoulute` from `#gallery-display [id^="image"] img` under your css so from

```
#gallery-display [id^="image"] img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -500px;
    border: 0px none;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-in 0s;
}
```

to

```
#gallery-display [id^="image"] img {
    top: -500px;
    border: 0px none;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-in 0s;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work...I am not sure why you are getting upvotes

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bWk24/4/
Add this to CSS:

```
       #gallery-display [id^='image']:target img {
            top: 0; 
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 500px;
            left: 0; //Add this property
            right: 0;   //Add this property
        }
```

Comment: Works for me. Which browser are you using ? Your link is different than mine

Comment: @JosephMarikle Ahh !...I see what you mean. Updated my answer

Comment: This only approximately centers one of the images. The rest are noticeably  misaligned.

Comment: @BrandonGano No. They are perfectly aligned in center with respect to black background. Check for yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/bWk24/4/show/

Comment: Ani, you are correct. It works now that you've switched over to use a similar solution to that suggested by @Artur Käpp (the accepted solution). My comment was referring to your original solution.